# Не работает автоинкрементирование . PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждая из которых заполнена данными. Таблица students и students_courses заполнены данными на 200 строк. 
В таблице students в колонке student_id стоит SERIAL для инкрементации. По задумке при добавлении новых данных в колонки group_id,first_name,last_name - student_id должен инкрементироваться автоматически.. 
Но, когда я добавляю новые данные в first_name и last_name след. образом:

```
INSERT INTO students (first_name,last_name) VALUES('Ivan','Ivanov');
```

вылезает ошибка: `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "students_pkey"
 Key (student_id)=(1) already exists.`

Почему программа думает, что я хочу поместить их в student_id = 1 ? Где моя ошибка ? Ведь это имя и фамилия должны добавиться следующими по счету, т.е под student_id = 201, а не быть вписаны в уже имеющийся student_id = 1.

Comment: как именно добавляли предыдущие 200 строк?

Comment: INSERT INTO students (student_id, group_id, first_name, last_name)
VALUES (1, 1, 'Michael', 'Kalashnikov'),
(2, 1, 'Michael', 'Suvorov'),
(3, 1, 'Michael', 'Costin'),
(4, 1, 'Michael', 'Menshikov'),
(5, 1, 'Michael', 'Khazbulatov'),
(6, 1, 'Michael', 'Ivanov'),
(7, 1, 'Michael', 'Izmaylov'),
(8, 1, 'Michael', 'Fedorov'),
(9, 1, 'Michael', 'Petrov') и тд.

Comment: INSERT INTO students_courses (student_id, course_id)
VALUES (1,1),
(2,1),
(3,1),
(4,1),
(5,1),
(6,1),
(7,1),
(8,1),
(9,1) и тд

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> INSERT INTO students (student_id, group_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (1, 1, 'Michael', 'Kalashnikov')...

Ну собственно всё работает как задумано. Вы вставляли значения поля сиквенса вручную. Сиквенс не заботится об ошибках пользователя.

Строго говоря, псевдотип `serial` - это сокращение от `create sequence` и типа данных `int` с `default nextval(имя_сиквенса)`. Если вы вручную указываете значение этого поля при записи данных `nextval` не вызывается, равно как и никаким другим способом нижележащий сиквенс не информируется о том что вы делаете что-то странное. Поэтому последующий вызов `nextval` генерирует значение как обычно - 1. Полученную строку со значением 1 база пытается вставить в таблицу, обновляет индексы и обнаруживает что значение 1 в этом поле уже есть.

Если необходимо вставить строки с вручную указанными значениями - вам необходимо сдвинуть значение сиквенса самостоятельно вызовом `setval`. Так делает `pg_dump` в своей работе.

---

Если же рассматривать более стандартный синтаксис:

```
create temp table i3 (
   i int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, 
   v int
);
```

`GENERATED ALWAYS` вам вовсе запретит сделать `insert` с явным значением генерируемого поля.

`GENERATED BY DEFAULT` ведёт себя аналогично псевдотипу `serial`

Comment: Спасибо, за объяснение ! Исправил, работает :)